# Access database not connecting properly

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Just having a bit of an issue with a piece of code which I have used previously and has worked on other projects and not my current one.

```
Dim strdbPass As String = "pass"
Dim connString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=\\EPOS\bin\Debug\EPoSDb.aacdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=" & strdbPass & ";"
Dim strSearch As String
Dim MyConn As OleDbConnection
Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
Dim ds As DataSet
Dim tables As DataTableCollection
Dim source1 As New BindingSource
Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
Dim booFailLog As Boolean = False

Sub procFindStaffDB(ByVal strClerkID As String, ByRef booUserNotExists As Boolean)
    Dim strClerk As String = ""
    Dim strForename As String = ""
    Dim strSurname As String = ""
    Dim strShortName As String = ""
    Dim strLevel As String = ""
    Dim strClocked As String = ""

    MyConn = New OleDbConnection
    MyConn.ConnectionString = connString
    MyConn.Open()

    strSearch = "SELECT * FROM Staff WHERE ([ClerkID] = '" & strClerkID & "')"

    Dim cmd1 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(strSearch, MyConn)

    dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader
    While dr.Read()
        strClerk = dr("ClerkID").ToString
        strForename = dr("Forename").ToString
        strSurname = dr("Surname").ToString
        strShortName = dr("Short Name").ToString
        strLevel = dr("Level").ToString
        strClocked = dr("Clocked").ToString
    End While
    MyConn.Close()

    If strClerkID <> strClerk Then
        booUserNotExists = True
    Else
        booUserNotExists = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Added break points down to `Myconn.open()` and a few lines after but after opening the connection it jumps out of the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the file extension:

```
...EPoSDb.aacdb;Jet OLEDB...
```

should be

```
...EPoSDb.accdb;Jet OLEDB...
```

Comment: thanks for the correction, but it's still jumping out and i can't see why

Comment: just put 2 message box's either side of the myConn.open() and it's displaying the first message but not the second one

Comment: It should not just "jump out". An exception should be raised?

Comment: it's getting to MyConn.open() then returning to the form with no exception or running the rest of the procedure

Comment: Do you have a `Try/Catch` block around the call of `procFindStaffDB()`?

Comment: just added it and it's not throwing anything out at all

Comment: An exception should at least be visible in the output-window in Visual Studio. Are you sure the path to your accdb-file is correct, because as it's wrote it looks like a UNC path, but I suspect it's on the local drive?

Comment: So I left this project for a week and a half and came back to it with fresh thoughts. Put the code that runs the database procedure into a direct control from the button when pressed and it threw an error '"microsoft.ACE.12.0' is not registered". Was just a simple case of downloading it and it ran fine. Just don't understand why it wouldn't throw the error when running the procedure from a Select Case.